# Extract area from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I know how to extract a node out of the OSM planet file with osmosis.

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=h:/poi/planet-latest.osm.pbf --node-key-value 
keyValueList="shop.chocolate" --write-xml H:/poi/todo/chocolateshop.xml
```

But what if I want to extract an area like a "natural.beach"?
These are not "nodes" but "closed ways".

Can anyone help me to extract a "natural.beach" with OSM Planet file and Osmosis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [osmosis in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). The page has [lots of osmosis usage examples](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage) as well as an additional [separate example page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Examples). For a full parameter overview see [Osmosis/Detailed Usage](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage).

I've never used osmosis myself but it seems like you just need to specify `--way-key-value keyValueList="natural.beach" --used-node` instead of `--node-key-value`.

Comment: Thanks, I give it a shot.

Comment: I cant get it to work. I keep getting an emtpy file when it is completed

Comment: Really? I just used osmosis for the first time and tried the following call: `osmosis --read-xml file=test.xml --way-key-value keyValueList="natural.beach" --used-node --write-xml file=out.xml`. It worked almost perfectly except for including some relations.

Comment: Follow-up: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/36083/extract-beaches-from-planet-file