# How to extract part of huge osm.pbf in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap

I have a huge osm file (>3 Gb), which doesn't run in jupyter

```
from pyrosm import OSM
from pyrosm import get_data
path=r"\*.osm.pbf" 
osm = OSM(path)
drive_net = osm.get_network(network_type="driving")
drive_net.plot()
```

(memory error when i tried `osm.get_network(network_type="driving")`).

So I have lat-lon coordinates set and I want to choose an area that would include all these coordinates and a little bit around them.

Is there way to extract area in python for next work with this data (final goal is route between this coordinates)?

Answer (score 2):

If it does not need directly to be in Python, you can use Osmosis CLI to pre-process the data and then feed it into your jupyter Notebook.

[Extract area from OpenStreetMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426172/extract-area-from-openstreetmap)

(written in Java, so it will not be directly usable in Python I think).

An alternative with similar feature is [Osmium](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmium) which has [Python Bindings](https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/).

As for building up the area, you could use them as the points of a polygon and extrude the resulting polygon. See also here: https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-extract.html